# Odoo search Control panel model extension failed to evaluate domain

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

Im doing the [odoo getting started tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/07_basicviews.html) and I get an error that I dont understand and dont know how to debug it. Im adding the search record, and have the following now.

```
<record id="estate_property_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">estate.property.view.search</field>
    <field name="model">estate.property</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Search Opportunities">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="postcode"/>
            <field name="expected_price"/>
            <field name="bedrooms"/>
            <field name="living_area"/>
            <field name="facades"/>
            <filter string="Available" name="available" domain="[('date_availability', '=', context_today() )]"/>
            <filter string="Archived" name="inactive" domain="  [('active',            '=', False           )]"/>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

The archived filter is working correctly, the available filter is giving me the error:

```
Error: Control panel model extension failed to evaluate domain:/n{}
```

I'm pretty sure that this error is the result of code that is not correct because if I replace it `False`, then it works, and if I replace it with something random like `toooday()` then i get the same error. However, I see many examples on the internet using this code so I think it should work. I also tried `odoo.fields.Date.context_today()` and that doesnt work either.

Comment: Which Odoo version are you working with?

Comment: It could be that Odoo is evaluating the domain on module update to get a safe domain for later use. So `context_today()` alone is not working when evaluating because you can't use a pure `date` object in a domain. Just add `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` to it, and it should evaluate without an error.

Comment: @CZoellner Im working with odoo 14.0. 
Your suggestion to add `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` did fix the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that Odoo is evaluating the domain on module update to get a safe domain for later use.

So `context_today()` alone is not working when evaluating because you can't use a pure `date` object in a domain. Just add `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` to it, and it should evaluate without an error.